# Basic Pact/Junit5 Test Setup fails. No method annotated with @Pact was found for provider error

Tags: java, spring, junit5, pact

I tried to follow the documentation on Pact.io to write a simple integration test.
Unfortunately i get an exception as follows:

```
 org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter [au.com.dius.pact.consumer.MockServer mockServer] in method [public void com.example.demo.integration.pact.PactTest.setUp(au.com.dius.pact.consumer.MockServer)]: No method annotated with @Pact was found on test class PactTest for provider 'node_server'
```

It says that I don't have any method annotated with @Pact. However I do have a method, which is annotated with @Pact.

I tried to run the test manually and with 'mvn test' as well.

The application in general is providing some Rest Controllers, which should be tested.

Following is all I have implemented regarding my Pact Test Implementation. Am I missing something?

```
package com.example.demo.integration.pact;

import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.MockServer;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.dsl.PactDslWithProvider;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.PactConsumerTestExt;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.PactTestFor;
import au.com.dius.pact.core.model.RequestResponsePact;
import au.com.dius.pact.core.model.annotations.Pact;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

import java.io.IOException;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;


@ExtendWith(PactConsumerTestExt.class)
@PactTestFor(providerName = PactTest.PACT_PROVIDER_NAME)
public class PactTest {

    public static final String PACT_PROVIDER_NAME = "node_server";

    public static final String PACT_CONSUMER_NAME = "spring_application";

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(MockServer mockServer) {
        System.out.println("Mockserver check called");
        Assertions.assertTrue(mockServer != null);
    }

    @Pact(provider = PACT_PROVIDER_NAME, consumer = PACT_CONSUMER_NAME)
    public RequestResponsePact createPact(PactDslWithProvider builder) {

        return builder
                .uponReceiving("notes")
                .path("/notes")
                .method("GET")
                .willRespondWith()
                .matchHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
                .status(200)
                .body(
                        getJsonArrayOfNotes(2).toString())
                .toPact();
    }

    @Test
    @PactTestFor(pactMethod = "notes")
    void test(MockServer mockServer) throws IOException {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = Request.Get(mockServer.getUrl() + "/notes").execute().returnResponse();
        assertEquals(200, httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        assertEquals(getJsonArrayOfNotes(2).toString(),httpResponse.getEntity().getContent().toString());
    }

    private JSONArray getJsonArrayOfNotes(int size) {
        var responseJsonObject = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            var note = new JSONObject();
            try {
                note.put("title", String.format("Title %s", i + 1));
                note.put("content", String.format("Some Note Content of Note %s", i + 1));
            } catch (Exception exception) {

            }
            responseJsonObject.put(note);
        }
        return responseJsonObject;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the method name with the @Pact annotation must be the same as the pactMethod in the @PactTestFor annotation...

In my case I had to write following:

```
@Test
@PactTestFor(pactMethod = "getNotes")
void test(MockServer mockServer) throws IOException {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = Request.Get(mockServer.getUrl() + "/notes").execute().returnResponse();
        assertEquals(200, httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        assertEquals(getJsonArrayOfNotes(2).toString(),httpResponse.getEntity().getContent().toString());
    }

@Pact(provider = PACT_PROVIDER_NAME, consumer = PACT_CONSUMER_NAME)
public RequestResponsePact getNotes(PactDslWithProvider builder) {

        return builder
                .uponReceiving("notes")
                .path("/notes")
                .method("GET")
                .willRespondWith()
                .matchHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
                .status(200)
                .body(
                        getJsonArrayOfNotes(2).toString())
                .toPact();
    }
```

Comment: That's correct. You need to tie the unit test function (as denoted by the `@Test` annotation) with the `RequestResponsePact` it relates to. Thanks for updating your answer!