# Unable to run JUnit5 PACT test. No method annotated with @Pact was found on test class ConsumerContractTest for provider ''

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5, pact

I'm trying to get a PACT test running on JUnit5.  We use JUnit4 for others, but this one will be JUnit5.  The error occurs when running the JUnit5 test using the pact annotation on the `RequestResponsePact` method.

Error : `No method annotated with @Pact was found on test class ConsumerContractTest for provider ''`.

I've seen [Basic Pact/Junit5 Test Setup fails. No method annotated with @Pact was found for provider error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66008002/basic-pact-junit5-test-setup-fails-no-method-annotated-with-pact-was-found-for), but this is issue was due to the `@PactTestFor(pactMethod = "examplePact")` not matching the `@Pact` method name.  But on my code it does match.

I can't seem to figure out why I get the error and especially why the error has an empty provider(`provider ''`) despite defining one(`"some-provider"`).

Example code :

```
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.MockServer
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.Pact
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.dsl.PactDslJsonArray
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.dsl.PactDslWithProvider
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.PactConsumerTestExt
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.PactTestFor
import au.com.dius.pact.model.RequestResponsePact
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus


@ExtendWith(PactConsumerTestExt.class)
class ConsumerContractTest {


    @Pact(consumer = "some-consumer", provider = "some-provider")
    RequestResponsePact examplePact(PactDslWithProvider builder) {

        builder
                .given("provider state")
                .uponReceiving("Contract description")
                .method("GET")
                .matchPath("/endpoint")
                .willRespondWith()
                .status(200)
                .headers(["Content-Type": "application/vnd.pnf.v1+json"])
                .body(new PactDslJsonArray())
                .toPact()
    }

    @Test
    @PactTestFor(pactMethod = "examplePact")
    void exampleTest(MockServer mockServer) {
        def client = new RESTClient(mockServer.getUrl())
    }
}
```

Comment: I have some pact contracts using Junit5 written here if perhaps useful to you. https://github.com/francislainy/mbbackend/tree/master/src/test/java/com/example/mbbackend/pact/consumer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's just the gist you've posted here but I see the `return` word missing and also the `@PactTestFor` annotation missing the provider and version. Here is an example I have that works for my project.

```
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.dsl.DslPart;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.dsl.PactDslJsonBody;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.dsl.PactDslWithProvider;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.PactConsumerTestExt;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.PactTestFor;
import au.com.dius.pact.core.model.PactSpecVersion;
import au.com.dius.pact.core.model.RequestResponsePact;
import au.com.dius.pact.core.model.annotations.Pact;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static com.example.mbbackend.config.Constants.*;
import static com.example.mbbackend.util.Utils.getRequestSpecification;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@ExtendWith(PactConsumerTestExt.class)
class GetActorIT {

    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

    String path = "/api/mb/actor/";

    @Pact(provider = PACT_PROVIDER, consumer = PACT_CONSUMER)
    public RequestResponsePact createPact(PactDslWithProvider builder) {

        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

        DslPart bodyReturned = new PactDslJsonBody()
                .uuid("id", "1bfff94a-b70e-4b39-bd2a-be1c0f898589")
                .stringType("name", "A name")
                .stringType("family", "A family")
                .stringType("imageUrl", "http://anyimage.com")
                .close();

        return builder
                .given("A request to retrieve an actor")
                .uponReceiving("A request to retrieve an actor")
                .pathFromProviderState(path + "${actorId}", path + "1bfff94a-b70e-4b39-bd2a-be1c0f898589")
                .method("GET")
                .headers(headers)
                .willRespondWith()
                .status(200)
                .body(bodyReturned)
                .toPact();
    }

    @Test
    @PactTestFor(providerName = PACT_PROVIDER, port = PACT_PORT, pactVersion = PactSpecVersion.V3)
    void runTest() {

        //Mock url
        RequestSpecification rq = getRequestSpecification().baseUri(MOCK_PACT_URL).headers(headers);

        Response response = rq.get(path + "1bfff94a-b70e-4b39-bd2a-be1c0f898589");

        assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode());
    }

}
```